# How to remove everything after a certain character? (notepad++)

Tags: regex, notepad++

I need to remove everything after a certain character. 
For example in the following line:

```
email:pass | text | text | text | text
```

How would I remove everything past the `"pass"` so it ends up like this :

```
email:pass
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Do a find replace (replacing with nothing) this regex:

```
\|.*
```

See https://regexr.com/3rq9m for explanation.

Comment: Don't forget to uncheck `. matches newline`.

Answer (score 21):

1. press **CTRL** +**Shift**
2. go to **replace**
3. press on regular expression
4. In the `Find what` write `[|].*`
5. press **Replace all**